# Angular2: Set Inputs type in a directive

Tags: typescript, angular

I have the following directive :

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[myDir]"
})
export class MyDir implements OnInit {
    private el:HTMLElement

    @Input() hide: boolean


    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement
    }

    ngInit() {
        console.log(typeof this.hide) // Writes string in the console
    }
}
```

Template :

```
<p myDirnumber=1 hide=false></p>
```

Is there anyway that I could force hide to take the boolean type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do what you want.

```
<p myDirnumber=1 [hide]="false">
```

Without `[]` Angular interprets the value as string instead of as expression.